# Bulk Insert Russian & other international Characters into SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, excel, sql-server-2008, import

When I use Bulk Insert on a tab delimited file (export from UNIX SAP system) into SQL Server 2008 R2 the `Short_text` field turns into hieroglyphics if they are extended characters like Russian.

My code is:

```
    BULK INSERT ProcureDB.dbo.tbl_SAP_PO_Load
    FROM \\Path\'Bulk_Insert_test.txt'
    WITH
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
      ,FIRSTROW=2
      ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

This is how the short text field looks:

```
Short_Text
╤ü╤é╨░╨║╨░╨╜╤ï ╨╛╨┤╨╜╨╛╤Ç╨░╨╖╨╛╨▓╤ï╨╡                                                                                                                 
╤ç╨░╨╣ ╤ç╨╡╤Ç╨╜╤ï╨╣                                                                                                                          
Dell 22" Touch screen                                                                                                                   
Dell 3 yr advanced exchange svc
```

The first two lines are Russian. If I import this into Excel using the text import wizard, it uses Code-page 65001 by default (65001 : Unicode (UTF-8) and the Russian text comes out OK in the Excel sheet

```
Short_Text (in excel sheet)
стаканы одноразовые                                                                                                                 
чай черный                                                                                                                          
Dell 22" Touch screen                                                                                                                   
Dell 3 yr advanced exchange svc
```

One of the suggestions on the web was to use Code-page 65001 in the Bulk Insert.

Hence the code:

```
    BULK INSERT ProcureDB.dbo.tbl_SAP_PO_Load
    FROM \\Path\'Bulk_Insert_test.txt'
    WITH
    (
       **CODEPAGE = '65001'**
      ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
      ,FIRSTROW=2
      ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

However this yields the error:

> Msg 2775, Level 16, State 13, Line 3
>   The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.

How can I get code page 65001 to be supported by the Server?

Another suggestion was using CODEPAGE = 'ACP'. This works, however, the Russian characters are corrupted but in a different way.

```
Short_Text
ÑÑ‚Ð°ÐºÐ°Ð½Ñ‹ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ð¾Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ðµ                                                                                                                 
Ñ‡Ð°Ð¹ Ñ‡ÐµÑ€Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹                                                                                                                          
Dell 22" Touch screen                                                                                                                   
Dell 3 yr advanced exchange svc
```

Version info. is below:

- Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) 10.50.6000.34
- Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601) NT x64
- English (United States)
- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score -1):

When I had the same problem, I created my own workaround. The UTF-8 text file I was importing was created/updated by another app, so I couldn't change file format.

1. My Database has Collation `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.
2. All columns that will contain Russian are declared as `nchar()` or `nvarchar()`.
3. I `BULK INSERT` my tab delimited text file into temp table:

   truncate table tempTable
   bulk insert tempTable from 'C:\Users...\MyFile.txt' 
       with(DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
           FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 1251)

As a result, I am getting fields that look like this:

```
РђР‘Р’Р“Р”Р•РЃР–Р—РР™РљР›РњРќРћРџР РЎРўРЈР¤РҐР¦Р§РЁР©РЄР«Р¬Р­Р®РЇР
```

4. To decode that, I created a table and a function:

   ```
   declare @Codes char(200), @Letters char(100)
   if exists(select * from sys.objects where name = 'bDecode') 
   drop table bDecode
   create table bDecode(Code nvarchar(2), Letter nvarchar(1))
   set @Codes = 
   'РђР‘Р’Р“Р”Р•РЃР–Р—РР™РљР›РњРќРћРџР РЎРўРЈР¤РҐР¦Р§РЁР©РЄР«Р¬Р­Р®РЇР°Р±РІРіРґРµС‘Р¶Р·РёР№РєР»РјРЅРѕРїСЂСЃС‚СѓС„С…С†С‡С€С‰СЉС‹СЊСЌСЋСЏ'
   set @Letters = 
   'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
   declare @i int set @i = 1 while @i <= len(@Letters) 
   begin
       insert into bDecode(Code, Letter) 
       select  substring(@Codes, @i * 2 - 1, 2),
               substring(@Letters,@i,1)
       set @i = @i + 1
   end
   GO
       CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Decode](@Name nvarchar(500)) returns nvarchar(500) as BEGIN 

   --select top 10 * from tmpAuthors
   --declare @Name nvarchar(500) set @Name = 'РђР‘Р’Р“Р”Р•РЃР–Р—РР™РљР›РњРќРћРџ'

       declare @i int, @NameCode nchar(2), @TableCode nchar(2), @Letter nchar(1)

       set @i = 1 while @i < len(@Name) begin

           set @NameCode = substring(@Name,@i,2)

           if exists(select 1 from bDecode where Code = @NameCode 
               and unicode(right(Code,1)) = unicode(right(@NameCode,1))) begin
   --print @Name
               select @TableCode = Code, @Letter = Letter 
               from bDecode where Code = @NameCode
                   and unicode(right(Code,1)) = unicode(right(@NameCode,1))

               set @Name = left(@Name, @i - 1) + @Letter + right(@Name, len(@Name) - @i - 1)
           end

       set @i = @i + 1 end

   --print @Name

   --------------------------------------------

       RETURN @Name
   END
   GO
   ```
5. Now I perform decode:

   ```
   update tempTable set Name = dbo.fn_Decode(Name)
   ```

This works for me.

Comment: Please neaten this up so that what you are trying to say is intelligible.

Comment: I tried to format this answer and the editor won't allow it to be saved when all of the code is put in a code block...